# How delete rows where `row[patient_id]` is duplicated and `row[Target]==0`?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I want delete all rows from my .csv file where:

1) `row[patient_id]` are duplicated

2) `row[Target] == 0`

Name of cols:
`patientId      x  y  w  h  Target`

```
patientId        x      y     w       h      Target
'2341-vcb1'    '10'   '20'   '30'   '40'      '1'
'2341-vcb1'    '70'   '20'   '70'   '40'      '1'
'2341-vcb1'                                   '0'   <-delete it
'1111-xcsc'                                   '0'
'2341-v233'    '34'   '43'   '10'   '29'      '1'
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrdIk.png)

df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset='patientId' && ??? )

Comment: Can you provide some sample input? perhaps a few rows from your CSV. Also post code you have tried, even if it doesn't work. It helps us help you faster.

Comment: Yea. I added an image.

Comment: Please, no images of code or data. Post it formatted as code, i.e. indented by 4 chars.

Comment: Ok. One minute.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is to create a column where you calculate the cumulative sum of target. You first sort the df by patientId and then target in descending order, then use groupby and cumsum function to add up the target (call it target_sum). Once you have that column, you can delete rows where target = 0 and target_sum > 0.

The logic behind it:

- if the id has other valid rows above the row where target == 0 (since we already sorted it), target_sum should be >0. Thus if we see that target_sum >0, we know this row has a duplicated id.
- if target_sum = 0, it means that particular id does not have any other rows with valid values, thus we want to keep it.

---

```
df['target_sum'] = df.sort_values(by=['patientID','Target'], ascending=False).Target.groupby('patientID').cumsum()

df = df[~ (df['Target'] == 0) & (df['target_sum' > 0])]
```

Comment: TypeError: sort_values() got an unexpected keyword argument 'descending'

Comment: I changed to : `ascending=False` but I got another error:

Comment: `ValueError: level name patientId is not the name of the index`

Comment: You are right. it should be ascending=False. My bad. let me fix it.

Comment: try groupby('patientID'), without level. (level is used if it has multi-index and if patientID is one of your indices).

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
import numpy as np

df[~np.logical_and(df.patientId.duplicated(), df.Target==0)]

# patientId     x     y     w     h  Target
# 0  2341-vcb1  10.0  20.0  30.0  40.0       1                
# 1  2341-vcb1  70.0  20.0  70.0  40.0       1                
# 3  1111-xcsc   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN       0             
# 4  2341-v233  34.0  43.0  10.0  29.0       1
```

Comment: `19  010ccb9f-6d46-4380-af11-84f87397a1b8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  0`

Comment: `20  010ccb9f-6d46-4380-af11-84f87397a1b8  301.0  405.0  141.0  279.0  1`

Comment: Maybe df.Target is a string?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your first three comments, but you can check the data type of your columns by `print(df.dtypes)`